# PowerBI DAX - Filter Total based on selected columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the table that looks like this:

```
Column Header:     User     | Test Score 1 | Test Score 2 | Test Score 3 | Total Points | Status
Row:                Person1 |      50      |      70      |      75      |     195      | Failed 
Row:                Person2 |      70      |      75      |      85      |     210      | Passed
```

The "Total Points" column is simply the SUM of the three test scores and the "Status" is calculated based on the "Total Points" (if "Total Points" < 200, "Failed", "Passed").

What I'm having difficulty with is that sometimes a test needs to be eliminated from the equation. I would like the end user to be able to uncheck a box in the filters area or on a slicer to remove a test from the equation for the "Total Points", which would then affect the "Status". Since the test is a column header and not a value, I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The data table is already in a report layout. That makes your intention difficult to process. A better layout would be a flat table in this format:

Name, Test number, Score

You can use Power Query to unpivot the data to get from your layout to the flat table. With a flat table, you can then build a measure for the total and add a slicer to the report where the test number can be selected.

Build a matrix visual with the Name in the rows and the test number in the columns, the measure for the total in the values. Then use the slicer to remove tests from the matrix at your discretion.

[image]
[image]
[image]